Variable in Directory.Build.Props not working for old-style csproj format
I tried using Directory.Build.props to setup some variables for use with our different project types.
<Project>

   <PropertyGroup>
       <!-- For SDK style c# projects -->
       <ApmTargetFramework>net481</ApmTargetFramework>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <PropertyGroup>
      <ApmTargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8.1</ApmTargetFrameworkVersion>
   </PropertyGroup>      
      
   <PropertyGroup>
       <!-- For APM multi-targeted projects-->
       <ApmMultiTargetFrameworks>net6.0;net481</ApmMultiTargetFrameworks>
   </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

For the sdk style projects both of these work:
<TargetFrameworks>$(ApmMultiTargetFrameworks)</TargetFrameworks>

and
<TargetFramework>$(ApmTargetFramework)</TargetFramework>

In the old-style csproj files it doesn't seem to be working:
<TargetFrameworkVersion>$(ApmTargetFrameworkVersion)</TargetFrameworkVersion>


It seems to be working in the SDK style projects with and without multi-targeting.
It seems like it is probably coming up as "blank" or empty in the old-style csproj files.
As a test, I tried manually setting a value in the UI.

This showed up in the project file as:
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>


From "Target framework and profile" v4.8 is a supported value for TargetFrameworkVersion.  Can you test and see if <ApmTargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</ApmTargetFrameworkVersion> works? It may be that V4.8.1 is simply not recognized.

Thanks for the idea.  v4.8 still didn't let me load the projects.  I had everything compiling with v4.8.1 but then I was trying to use Directory.Build.props to have some common variables so I wouldn't have 200 csproj files with v4.8.1 hardcoded in them.  It seems to be working for SDK style projects.  Not sure what is going on with the older style projects.

https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/4175

Looking through some of the documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2017/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2017#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets

Directory.Build.props is imported very early in
Microsoft.Common.props, and properties defined later are unavailable
to it. So, avoid referring to properties that are not yet defined (and
will evaluate to empty).

When I looked, some of our project files did not include Microsoft.Common.props.  We have some of our own .props files and I think someone might have removed Microsoft.Common.props.
e.g. files that did not include this, did not work with Directory.Build.props
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />

